# "une dizaine de fois" vs "une douzaine de fois": Which phrasing comes more naturally to French speakers?

Tags: nombres

> J'ai déjà dû répéter tout ça **une dizaine de** fois.
>
> J'ai déjà dû répéter tout ça **une douzaine de** fois.

Here, I'm not talking about the exact number of times I've done something, but rather I want to emphasise a moderately large number.

I wonder which of these two numbers French speakers use more commonly: ten or a dozen?

The same goes for:

> Si seulement j'avais eu ne serait-ce qu’**une** **dizaine**/**douzaine** **de** personnes coopératives autour de moi !

Answer (score 1):

We still use *douzaines* for eggs, oysters, snails and a few other delicacies but for "a moderate number of times", while *une douzaine* is certainly idiomatic too, my impression is *une dizaine* prevails.

Google Ngram shows the metric system in action:

[image]

Comment: Metric? or do you mean decimal?

Comment: "Si seulement j'avais eu ne serait-ce qu’une **dizaine/douzaine** de personnes coopératives autour de moi !" Would you prefer "dizaine" when saying this, too?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Le système métrique à popularisé le comptage par dizaines alors que les douzaines (ou les vingtaines) prévalaient sous l'ancien régime. C'est cette corrélation que montre, à mon avis, cette courbe où la dizaine ne décolle que dans la première moitié du XIXe siècle.

Comment: @Alone-zee Yes, I guess I would tend to use *dizaine* here.

Comment: On the other hand (literally ;-)  I would definitely say *une demi-douzaine* and never *une demi-dizaine*...

Comment: Now that you mention it, I see a bundle of ***6*** bottles of mineral water on sale, but not a bundle of ***5***. I wonder if this explains why "une demi-douzaine" is preferred? The idea of "***ten/five*** fingers" seems just as logical, though. ;)

Comment: Five is too difficult to split in two equal parts...

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are looking for colloquialisms.
In this instance, "douzaine" is better if you want to express, let's say, annoyance. But what would come naturally to me is "une demi-douzaine"
- j'ai dû lui répéter ça une demi-douzaine de fois
numerically inferior but rhythmically superior sentencewise, if you see what I mean.